# How to solve my problem in Excel ledger sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am not an Excel expert. I created a ledger sheet that I want to work fully automatically. In this sheet I pass any entry then serial number date and debit credit are all working automatically. Now here comes the problem that when I drag down the cr dr column it shows me reptealy cr dr. I want I add a value to my debit or credit it is automatically shown in the balance. If the value in balance is in negative or in debit then I show dr. And if the value in the balance column is credit then I show cr. And if there is no value in the balance column then I get nothing in the dr column.

[image]

Comment: Welcome @Muhammad Umair. Pl format the question correctly so that it can be easily understood.

Comment: Pls. try this `=IF(G5="","",IF(G5>0,"Cr","Dr"))`